# Scraping text from a header and Class tag

Tags: python, web-scraping

The code below errors out when trying to execute this line 
**"RptTime = TimeTable[0].xpath('//text()')"**
Not sure why I see TimeTable has a value in my variable window, but the HtmlElement **"TimeTable[0]"** has no value and the **"content.cssselect"** at time of assignment returns value. Why then would I get an error **"list index out of range"**. This tells me that the element is empty. I am trying to get the Year Month value in that field.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from lxml import html
import requests

def http_request_get(url, session=None, payload=None, parse=True):
""" Sends a GET HTTP request to a website and returns its HTML content and full url address. """

    if payload is None:
      payload = {}

    if session:
       content = session.get(url, params=payload, verify=False, headers={"content-type":"text"})
    else:
       content = requests.get(url, params=payload, verify=False, headers={"content-type":"text"})

    content.raise_for_status()  # Raise HTTPError for bad requests (4xx or 5xx)

    if parse:
       return html.fromstring(content.text), content.url
    else:
       return content.text, content.url

def get_html(link):
  """
  Returns a html.
  """
   page_parsed, _ = http_request_get(url=link, payload={'t': ''}, parse=True)
   return page_parsed


cmslinks=[
'https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Contract-and-Enrollment-Summary-Report?items_per_page=100&items_per_page_options%5B5%5D=5%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B10%5D=10%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B25%5D=25%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B50%5D=50%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B100%5D=100%20per%20page&combine=&page=0',
'https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Contract-and-Enrollment-Summary-Report?items_per_page=100&items_per_page_options%5B5%5D=5%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B10%5D=10%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B25%5D=25%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B50%5D=50%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B100%5D=100%20per%20page&combine=&page=1']


df=pd.DataFrame()
df2=pd.DataFrame()
for cmslink in cmslinks:
   print(cmslink)
   content, _ = http_request_get(url=cmslink,payload={'t':''},parse=True)
   linkTable = content.cssselect('td[headers="view-dlf-1-title-table-column"]')[0]
   TimeTable = content.cssselect('td[headers="view-dlf-2-report-period-table-column"]')[0]
   headers = linkTable[0].xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contract Summary') or contains(text(),'Monthly Enrollment by CPSC')]/@href")
   RptTime =  TimeTable.xpath('//text()')  
   dfl = pd.DataFrame(headers,columns= ['links'])
   dft = pd.DataFrame(RptTime,columns= ['ReportTime'])
   df=df.append(dfl)
   df2=df.append(dft)
```

Error

```
src\lxml\etree.pyx in lxml.etree._Element.__getitem__()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please, edit the code by taking care of the indentation. Current code isn't well indented. It seams you are applying two first element selection using `[0]` at `content.cssselect('...')[0]` and `RptTime = TimeTable[0].xpath('//text()')`

Comment: you also havent provided all the code. `df1 = pd.DataFrame(headers,columns= ['RptTime'])` wheres your `headers` variable?

Comment: also, do you mean to get the index `0` twice? `TimeTable = content.cssselect('td[headers="view-dlf-2-report-period-table-column"]')[0]`, then `TimeTable[0].xpath('//text()') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully at your last line. `df = df.append(df1)`. Your explanation and code is quite unclear due to indenting and error traceback however this is obviously not what you intended.

`df.append(df1)` is a procedure rather than strictly a function, it does not return anything. You simply write the line and it does its magic similar to `print("hi")` rather than `this_is_wrong = print("hi")`.

What would end up happening is you overwrite `df` will `null` which should be causing some major errors if you ever use that variable again. However, this is not the cause of your problem I thought it my duty to tell you anyway.

Could you please tell us **exactly** what is returned by the `css...` function. Although you said it returned something you only store the `[0]` index of the return value. Meaning that if it is `["","something"]` hypothetically, the value stored would be `null`.

It is quite likely that the problem you are having is that **you indexed `[0]` twice**, when you probably only meant to do it once.

Comment: Thank you for the help TimeTable = <Element td at 0x216fa4774f8>. The Links extraction works without a problem so in order to make it easier I removed that part of the code. I added it back now as i only caused more confusion. I need to extract dates thats my current issue. Updates have been made

Comment: In other words the linkTable[0] element has a value and TimeTable[0] has no value and these tags are almost identtical.

Comment: removed the 0 index and didnt get error but it returned all the text on the page. That an improvement. I believe i just need correct xpath to only return dates

Comment: I needed to change the RptTime to --> RptTime = TimeTable.xpath('//td[@class="views-field views-field-dlf-2-report-period"]/text()')